How to work with NTC thermistor (ntcascwe3103f)
I was getting wrong temperature value. Not up-to the mark.
like if I change the value of temperature in heater from 40 to 60 degree Celsius, then it was giving the output 55 or some more difference.
#define ANF6 46
#define ADC_VREF 3.3
#define ADC_FACTOR (ADC_VREF/1023.0)
#define RESISTANCE_REF 4700
#define RESISTANCE_FROM_VOLTAGE(v) (((ADC_VREF/v)-1) * RESISTANCE_REF)

float temperature_from_resistance(float resistance) {
  const float A = 0.001112048; 
  const float B = 0.000224458; 
  const float C = 1.1114E-06;  
  const float D = 5.09066E-08; 

  return 1/(A + B*log(resistance) + C*pow(log(resistance), 2) + D*pow(log(resistance), 3)) - 273.00;
}

float get_temperature_from_sensor_1() {
  return temperature_from_resistance(RESISTANCE_FROM_VOLTAGE((float)(ADC_FACTOR * ADC_Read(ANF6))));
}


int main(){
      float temperature  = get_temperature_from_sensor_1();
      printf("%.2f\n", temperature);

}

Am I doing something wrong in this code?
I am running this code in mikroC pro for PIC compiler.
This is the sensor code: NTC thermistor (ntcascwe3103f)
I have tried this the given code but it was giving me wrong result.
Is someone is using the this sensor or someone had worked on this sensor?

There would have to be some temperature curve for the component as base for everything. Without that, it's just random math written down at a whim and nobody can troubleshoot it.

I suggest at the outset that you use a decent calibrated multimeter to measure the voltage across your sensor at room temperature before you go looking for software faults. The most likely cause of trouble is that the reference resistor and the sensor have very different values.
Otherwise the software doesn't look too wrong apart from the terrible way that you have computed the polynomial in log(r) which will be both glacially slow and somewhat inaccurate. The optimiser might save you but I doubt it.
Also beware that without a trailing f floating point constants default to doubles in standard C although not necessarily so on some embedded compilers.
#define ANF6 46
#define ADC_VREF 3.3f
#define ADC_FACTOR (ADC_VREF/1023.0f)
#define RESISTANCE_REF 4700.0f
#define RESISTANCE_FROM_VOLTAGE(v) (((ADC_VREF/v)-1.0f) * RESISTANCE_REF)

float temperature_from_resistance(float resistance) {
const float A = 0.001112048f; 
const float B = 0.000224458f; 
const float C = 1.1114E-06f;  
const float D = 5.09066E-08f; 
float lnr = log(resistance);
// evaluated using Horner's method with minimum multiplies
return 1.0f/(A + (B + (C + D*lnr)*lnr)*lnr) - 273.00f;
}   

float get_temperature_from_sensor_1() {
   return temperature_from_resistance(RESISTANCE_FROM_VOLTAGE((float) 
(ADC_FACTOR * ADC_Read(ANF6))));
}

Vishay don't provide calibration coefficients on their datasheet and insist that you download their bloated calculation tool as an macro enabled Excel spreadsheet. Check your calculations against that...
Mocking it up in a spreadsheet to check against their calibration graphs might help you check that the formula is working correctly.
